# How to merge rows using pandas if they have duplicate values?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, duplicates

I have a specific case with my data which I’m unable to find an answer to in any documentation or on stack.

What I’m trying to do is merge duplicates based on the ‘MPN’ Column (and not the Vehicle column).

There are going to be duplicates of MPNs in lots of rows as shown in the first image.

I obviously want to remove duplicate rows which have the same MPN, but MERGE the Category values from the three rows as shown in Image 1 in to one cell separated by colons as shown in Image Two, which would be my desired result after coded.

What I’m asking for: To be able to Merge and Remove duplicates based on rows that contain a duplicate MPN, and merge them in to ONE while retaining the categories separated by a colon.

Look at my before and after images to understand more clearly.

I’m also using Python 3.7 to code this from a csv file, separated by commas.

**Before:**

[image]

**After duplicates have merged:**
[image]

How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Please consider inserting a sample code and the desired output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming df holds you csv data. 
First group by based on common column(Vehicle and MNP) and make and update a common separated string on category column.

```
df['x'] = df.groupby(['foo','bar'])['x'].transform(lambda x: ':'.join(x))
```

Second remove duplicates

```
df.drop_duplicates()
```